# systemd: SSH service does not start at boot

Tags: ssh, systemd, boot, services, autostart

Whenever I boot my system (Ubuntu 16.04), I cannot log in via ssh and the service is reported as `inactive (dead)`

```
$ systemctl status ssh
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

So I try to enable it via

```
$ sudo systemctl enable ssh
Synchronizing state of ssh.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable ssh
```

I can start it manually with

```
$ sudo systemctl start  ssh
```

which then runs it successfully, but on every boot, same problem.

What can be the reason for this? How can I debug the problem?

For reference, the service file (installed by `openssh-sever` apt package) is this:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `journalctl -u ssh.service -b 0` directly after system start?

Comment: Our admin said the problem was that the ssh service does eventually start, but only after the Network Manager had initialised the interfaces, which seems to take an inordinate amount of time.
I will check it out and report back.